# Use of pronoun for objects in the preceding sentence

Tags: pronouns, subjects, direct-objects, indirect-objects

I am having some doubts regarding the use of pronouns. 
Please have a look at the following sentences.

1. > I picked a **pen** from the **dustbin** yesterday. 
   > ***It*** writes very smoothly.
2. > I picked a **pen** from the **dustbin** yesterday. 
   > ***It*** was full of plastic trash.

In the first example, I used the pronoun for the direct object (“pen”). 
However, in the second example,
I used the pronoun for the object of the preposition (“dustbin”).

Are both examples correct in the context of the use of pronouns? 
Or should I use the noun (“pen” or “dustbin”) instead of the pronoun?

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to the site!

The back-reference of personal pronouns, such as *it*, is usually free, but it depends on context. In this case, context makes the reference clear enough. I would say both sentences are perfectly fine.

In case of ambiguity, one could use a noun instead of a pronoun, as you suggested. Nouns can be made shorter if desired, such as *the bin*.

Alternatively, especially in somewhat formal genres, one can use *the former* and *the latter*, to refer to two things mentioned previously; *the latter* refers to the last (relevant) thing mentioned, *the former* to the other (relevant) thing mentioned in case there are only two relevant things to refer to.

Answer (score -2):

(1) is correct.

(2) would be understood, but is not strictly correct. In conversation, the speaker might add "The dustbin, that is" either at the end or after 'it'.